# rdiff-backup -r is not working with QT

Tags: restore, command-line-interface, rdiff-backup, qt

I am using rdiff-backup to get previous version of the files from server with this command:

```
rdiff-backup --no-hard-links --force  -r "DATE" "USERNAME@IP::SERVER PATH" "CLIENT PATH"
```

I can do this with command prompt  manually easily , but when i run this command via Qt i cannot get anything back . I can execute the command via QT locally.I mean there is no any problem with calling cmd and running command on it. Also i do not have enter password etc. to have an server access, but  When i want to execute the command with server via QT, i do not get anything.

```
rdiff-backup -l USERNAME@IP::SERVER PATH
```

For example i can execute this command with my application by calling cmd. But it does not work with  " --restore" command. Am i doing something wrong ?

Sorry if i did any mistake with my asking. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Qt is a graphics toolkit. What are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake i made here is sending path names with double quotations. If i send them without any quotation, then it works perfectly. When i write commands in command prompts with double quotation it works, but when i said command with QT then it does not work, but both do the same thing. So be sure that you do not include double quotation while sendind a command.